# How to disable Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

Is there a way to disable Jasmine test if there is some DOM-element on a page?

```
$(function() {

    if ( $('#id').length !== 0 ) {
        describe('some test', function() {
            // tests
        });
    };

});
```

The example above doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Also, you *don't* want to run the test if an element exists? Because your code is checking if the jQuery object's length is *not* 0, meaning that if it's 1, 2, 3, etc. (i.e. an element exists) the test *will* be run. I think you want `if ( $('#id').length === 0 )`.

Comment: The main problem is that `describe` doesn't work if I wrap it in `$(function() {})`

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you sure the jQuery source is included? Please be more specific.